# How to debug javascript in the new React Native architecture?

Tags: react-native

I couldn't find any documentation or any piece of information about how we will handle javascript debugging in the same or at least similar manner as we have already been doing in the current architecture like using `Attach to packager` or Chrome DevTools debugging options.

As far as I understand, currently we are using JSC for the main javascript engine, but when we start a debug session, instead of using JSC, it starts using the Chrome V8 engine since it allows us to use Chrome Developer Tools for easy debugging. Taken from [here](https://medium.com/@suyogkrazz/you-should-not-always-rely-on-remote-debugging-react-native-787a850c7ad8)

> When using Chrome debugging, it runs all the JavaScript code within
> Chrome itself and communicates with native code via WebSocket. So you
> are using V8.

With the new architecture, we must enable TurboModules first, but it completely disable the Debug option so we can not carry on using these traditional debugging options.

But it is also mentioned [here](https://formidable.com/blog/2019/jsi-jsc-part-2/) that we can theoretically use any javascript engine. So it can be Chrome v8 as well. Does it mean that we can use Chrome DevTools if we somehow enable to tell JSI to use V8?

Answer (score -3):

Simple solution just use a service like https://sentry.io handels java and javascript errors and provide all the information you would need

Comment: This answer should be deleted, sentry is a fine enough service but this doesn't answer the question of how to debug.